# Joining condition for the same column

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables as shown in the image. I would like to join two table. As shown in thane tables, first row is matching exactly, but in the second row last 17 digits(WSAV_3PE_RET_0720) are matching. I would like join this one also. So there should be two conditions.

1. Exactly matching
2. Last 17 digits are matching.

How to write the code in this scenario. Here is my partial code.

```
Select *,t2.Balance from t1 left join t2 on t1.Place = t2.Place
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT t1.*, t2.Balance
FROM `project.dataset.table1` t1
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table2` t2
ON SUBSTR(REVERSE(t1.Place), 1, 17) = SUBSTR(REVERSE(t2.Place), 1, 17)
```

Comment: @Mikhali, thanks for your help. So this one is matching last 17 digits. Is it right? I want to set-up first condition also on the same join.

Comment: Above solution does both your conditions in one! Don't you see this via simple  testing?

Comment: @Mikhali, thanks for your help. So this one is matching last 17 digits. Is it right? I want to set-up first condition also on the same join. because in some cases we don't have last 17 digits in "Place" column. For example, we have "Broad Under 30 - Feed and Story" without last 17 digits, so we need to join this also.Appreciate your help.

Comment: As I already said - above solution covers both cases presented in your question. Isn't it true? If you have new question - please post new question with all relevant details so we will be able to help further. Meantime consider voting up and accept the answer if it answers your current question